# Parsing html tables using jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I am parsing tables using jsoup. I need to connect to division standing tables from this website: https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2006.html. Don't know how to parse tables because I need to use the same method for every division standing table, but the id is different for older seasons (e.g. `id="divs_standings_W"`, `"id="divs_standings_E"` and `"id="divs_standings_"`). Link to some older season: https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1950.html.

How can I check if the table with the given id exists and if it exists put it in a variable table? Don't have much relevant code.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1950.html").get();
Elements table = doc.select("table[id=\"divs_standings_\"]");
```

Comment: You can check if `table != null` - if true then it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [prefix matching](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). Use `table[id^="divs_standings_"]`. This will match all tables, with ids starting with `divs_standings_`:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1950.html").get();
Element table = doc.selectFirst("table[id^=\"divs_standings_\"]");
```

This will work for old and new seasons.

To wrap this in a method you can just use something like this:

```
private static void processTable(String url) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Element table = doc.selectFirst("table[id^=\"divs_standings_\"]");
    System.out.println(table);
}
```

and call it with both urls:

```
processTable("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1950.html");
processTable("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2006.html");
```

You also can use pattern matching if you have more complex ids. Check out the link above for this.